# How to change the value of all the inputs to lower or upper case? in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I got:

```
function doClickCaps(){
  cs = ++cs % 2
  var data = $("input.letters").val();
  data.toUpperCase() 
}
```

But It doesn't seem to work? ty

Comment: First off ..  Separate your statements with `semicolons` ..  `cs = ++cs % 2;` 
  --  `data.toUpperCase(); `

Comment: Just use $("input.letters").val().toUpperCase() will also work..your code seems to be OK.

Comment: But it doesn't work :/

Comment: Second .. What does your console say?  Any errors?   My guess is`data` is either not set, or null?

Comment: The console doesn't caught any errors.

Comment: what does `console.log($("input.letters").val());` print out?

Comment: It prints out 1

Comment: Is that the expected value?

Comment: Duplicate of [Modify the value of each textfield based on original value using jQuery](/q/24725927/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doClickCaps() {
    cs = ++cs % 2;
    $('input.letters').each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) which will loop over all the elements internally

```js
function doClickCaps() {
  $('input.letters').val((_, v) => v.toUpperCase());
}

doClickCaps()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="test1" type="text" class="letters" />
<input type="text" value="fsdf" class="letters" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
function doClickCaps(){
           
      $('input[class=letters]').each(function(){
            var data = $(this).val();
            console.log(  data.toUpperCase() );
      })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="test1" type="text"  class="letters" />
<input type="text" value="fsdf" class="letters" />
<input type="button" value="TransformCase"onclick="doClickCaps()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **jquery** you can do something like this

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#Upper").click(function() {
    $('.texttomanu > .letters').val($('.texttomanu > .letters').val().toUpperCase());
  });
  $( "#Lower").click(function() {
    $('.texttomanu > .letters').val($('.texttomanu > .letters').val().toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texttomanu">
  <input type="text" class="letters" />
  <button id="Upper">Upper case</button>
  <button id="Lower">Lower case</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't work with more than one input with that class. Not instance specific

Comment: He can change the query selector as he like , the objectif is to toggle between upper case and lower case ^^'

Comment: Add one more `<input class="letters">` to your demo. You will see what I mean. .... *"change the value of **all** the inputs"*

Comment: @charlietfl how about containing that input inside a div

Comment: The issue is you will set the same value on all of them. And that value will be the value of the first one found

Comment: if contain the input inside a div with class `texttomanu` that would not happend using `$('.texttomanu > .letters')`

Comment: If there is more than one that matches that selector yes it will. Really need a loop so you can isolate each instance. It works with one as you have it...any more and it breaks